# Stacked bar chart across multiple columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I managed to transform my initial dataset into this form:

```
   ElemId total_count coef_true coef_false coef_ratio
 1  a1           2         2          0          1
 2  a2           4         4          0          1
 3  a3           1         1          0          1
 4  a4           5         5          0          1
 5  a5           1         1          5          1
 6  a6           4         4          0          1
 7  a7           4         4          3          1
 8  a8           2         2          2          1
 9  a9           3         3          1          1
10  a10           1         1          4          1
```

Right now what am I trying to achieve is to plot stacked bar chart showing the coef_true and coef_false on single bars using ggplot, *while preserving order by coef_ratio*. Is there a way to do it without further transforming the dataset?

**EDIT.** Modifying data is OK, although I tried using melt with `melt(valves, measure.vars=c("init_true", "init_false"))` and the bar chart seems to loose ordering of coef_ratio.

Comment: You don't allow any `melt` operations, right? And second thing - You want two bars in each a separate colour for the `ElemId`, correct?

Comment: Sorry, quite imprecise statement of me. I was afraid that data manipulation will loose the order of the data, I allow melts etc. but I just want to have a chart with coefs for each `ElemId` while preserving the order of bars by `coef_ratio` that goes from 1 to 0

Comment: Can you show enough data or a subset that has both `coef_ratio` 1 and 0, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to plot coef values over `ElemId` where `ElemId` is reordered by `coef_ratio`. If this is the case, you could do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  gather(key, value, -c(coef_ratio, ElemId, total_count)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(ElemId, coef_ratio), value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = key)) +
  labs(x = "ElemId reordered by coef_ratio")
```

[image]

I modified the data so that `ElemId` `a10` has a `coef_ratio` of 0 to show the reordering of the x axis.

```
text <- "ElemId total_count coef_true coef_false coef_ratio
       1   a1           2         2          0          1
       2   a2           4         4          0          1
       3   a3           1         1          0          1
       4   a4           5         5          0          1
       5   a5           1         1          5          1
       6   a6           4         4          0          1
       7   a7           4         4          3          1
       8   a8           2         2          2          1
       9   a9           3         3          1          1
       10  a10          1         1          4          0"

df <- read.table(text = text, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```