# Stacked bar charts where each column is a bar chart with multiple columns in Altair

Tags: python, altair

I'd like to draw similar chart that was requested in
[Stacked bar chart across multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801705/stacked-bar-chart-across-multiple-columns)
but it's with R, I want to use Python, hopefully with Atair.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you have wide-form data, and you need to transform it to long-form data (see [Long Form vs. Wide Form data](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/data.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data) in Altair's docs).

One convenient way to handle this is with a [Fold Transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/fold.html). For example:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'label': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
    'value1': [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 4],
    'value2': [2, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 2],
})

alt.Chart(df).transform_fold(
  ['value1', 'value2'],
  as_=['column', 'value']
).mark_bar().encode(
  x='label:N',
  y='value:Q',
  color='column:N'
)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this with the current version of altair and get an AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get', any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: You have an incompatible version of the `jsonschema` package (see https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2496). You either need to update `altair` to the most recent version (4.2 or newer), or  you need to downgrade `jsonschema` to version 3.X.